# How to bypass proxy for local address in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, proxy

i want to test the web app which i am developing in windows phone 8.1. Web app is in my local network (10.*.*.*). I connected the phone with the network using WiFi proxy.

In Android and iOS i am able to bypass the proxy for my local address, In windows phone i am not able to bypass the proxy in windows phone.

is anyone bypassed the proxy in windows Phone? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @gsuresh92: Not able to find yet. If you find please share. Is this issue raised in ms developer forum?

Comment: i don't know about the forum. i tried using mhotspot and burp suite. First create a hotspot from your laptop and then connect  to that from your mobile using wifi with proxy as IP of hotspot. it worked for the requests (80) that are not secured. As yours is a local server, it should work. just give a try